# Using two different versions of ActiveX

Tags: c++, com, activex

I have two different versions of ActiveX.

Unfortunatelly they are both using the same CLSID. 
When I'm registering new version the old one is removed.

I want to use some controls from older version and some from new one.

How can I do that?

Is it possible to force new ActiveX to use different CLSID when registering? This should eliminate the problem of removing old version when registering new one?

Comment: Putting it simply, **no** (unless *you're* the developer of the library, at which point you can use whatever you want for your coclass ids, but I *highly* advise against it; they probably also share Prog-IDs).

Comment: It should be possible using the Activation Context concept introduced in Windows that also applies to COM. Not an easy task though. More information here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973913.aspx and here http://omnicognate.wordpress.com/2009/10/05/winsxs/

Comment: Yes they share ProgIDs. But I still doubt that there is no possibility to make things working...